# SEO friendly links with Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, href

I am trying to build a blog website using Node + Express JS. I would like to make it SEO friendly, because currently the links to the blogs are using Ids of the database. For example:

```
localhost:3000/posts/1
```

However, I want to have a link like this:

```
localhost:3000/posts/my-adventure/
```

I am following dev.to website and I see that they are using href not with ids, but with the article names. I am puzzled here because this doesn't seem to be efficient from performance perspective as the database would have to be searched by long strings?

```
<a href="/djangostars/choosing-python-for-web-development-top-16-pros-and-cons-4c4k" id="article-link-185734" class="index-article-link" aria-label="Main Story" data-featured-article="articles-185734">
</a>
```

I would like to ask your help on how I could implement this in my application. Currently I am using this type of route:

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const post = await db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $1",
    req.params.id
  );
  res.render("readPost", { title: post.title, post: post });
});
```

Comment: What is your concern about the DB? I don't see any problem in querying by a long string, as long as the field is indexed and you  don't query using functions such as `LIKE`, for example, your DB will do just fine

Comment: You can store the slugged title in another column...  I agree with @CarlosCrespo in that this isn't a point of concern.

Comment: Okay, so would this be a good approach: slugify the title of the post, add it to the column "slug" column in DB and then search the articles by that column?

Comment: The problem might come from the fact that you allow the input of the user to become the identifier of the post and in the moment 2 posts will have the same title then you have to make a deterministic algorithm to differentiate them. (Ex: "Anne has apple", "Anne had apple 1", etc where the end number is added by you...which starts to defy the initial idea of not showing numbers in the slug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (I prefer this)

**append the 'id' to the URL to make it unique**. (sth like localhost:3000/posts/my-adventure-1/)

Your code snippet mayn't change, except the db column type (if you have used number)

You can use [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify).

Another way

```
router.get("/:slug/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const post = await db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $1",
    req.params.id
  );
  res.render("readPost", { title: post.title, post: post });
});
```

https://medium.com/@thiscodeworks.com/implementing-url-slugs-on-express-node-js-5f5890431dea